# Try to complete the missing information in the text file and if you couldn't complete it put it in a new file using python

Tags: python

my code only splits completed and incomplete how to fix this code so that it can find the missing data if possible
this is an example of complete and missing data:

Complete:

```
"Ahmad Omar;802424333;10/4/2000;0550123456;A10B20;Audi;2018;15 April 2020;17 April 2020;350 c."
```

Missing data:

```
"Ahmad Omar;802424333;;0550123456;A10B20;Audi;2018;15 April 2020;17 April 2020;350*"
```

this my code

```
def splitCompleteAndIncomplete():
  f = open("temp.txt","r")
  count=0
  for line in f.xreadlines(  ): 
    count += 1
  incompleteFile = open("CarRentalMissing.txt","w")
  completeFile = open("CarRentalCompleted.txt","w")
  for row in f.readlines():
    l = row.split(";")
    incompleteFlag=0
    for i in l:
      if len(i) == 0:
        incompleteFlag=1
    if(incompleteFlag == 1):
      incompleteFile.write(row)
    else:
      completeFile.write(row)
  f.close()
splitCompleteAndIncomplete()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check for 2 flags, 1. if ";;" occurs, which means a value was skipped, 2. if the number of ";" is correct.

```
s_correct = r"Ahmad Omar;802424333;10/4/2000;0550123456;A10B20;Audi;2018;15 April 2020;17 April 2020;350 c."
s_missing = r"Ahmad Omar;802424333;;0550123456;A10B20;Audi;2018;15 April 2020;17 April 2020;350"

s_test = s_missing 

print("s_test has missing data: ", (s_missing.find(";;") != -1) | (s_missing.count(";") != 9))
# True
```